# subquery returning more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CG.SITEID,
       CR.COLLECTIONID,
       CG.COLLECTIONNAME,
       CASE
          WHEN CR.ARCHITECTUREKEY = 5
          THEN
             N'vSMS_R_System'
          WHEN CR.ARCHITECTUREKEY = 0
          THEN
             (SELECT BASETABLENAME
                FROM DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES
                     JOIN
                     COLLECTION_RULES
                        ON DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES.DISCARCHKEY =
                              COLLECTION_RULES.ARCHITECTUREKEY
                     JOIN
                     COLLECTIONS_G
                        ON COLLECTION_RULES.COLLECTIONID =
                              COLLECTIONS_G.COLLECTIONID
               WHERE COLLECTIONS_G.SITEID = (SELECT TOP 1 SOURCECOLLECTIONID FROM VCOLLECTIONDEPENDENCYCHAIN WHERE DEPENDENTCOLLECTIONID = CG.SITEID ORDER BY LEVEL DESC))
            ELSE (SELECT DA.BASETABLENAME FROM DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES DA WHERE DA.DISCARCHKEY=CR.ARCHITECTUREKEY) END AS TABLENAME
  FROM COLLECTIONS_G CG
  JOIN COLLECTIONS_L CL ON CG.COLLECTIONID=CL.COLLECTIONID
  JOIN COLLECTION_RULES CR ON CG.COLLECTIONID=CR.COLLECTIONID
  WHERE (CG.FLAGS&4)=4 AND CL.CURRENTSTATUS!=5
```

I am having a problem with the code above, around the line:

```
when cr.ArchitectureKey=0 then...
```

The problem is that the sub-query returns more than one value, and I'm not too sure how to invert the query so that I get rid of the error.

To make matters worse, `cr.ArchitectureKey` would normally join with `da.DiscArchKey`, but while `cr.ArchitectureKey` can have a value of 0, that does not exist in `da.DiscArchKey`, meaning if I join the two directly I lose data.

**EDIT**

More information regarding the problem itself:

This is a stored procedure for a Microsoft product that has a 'bug' (probably considered a feature though) which I'm trying to fix. Don't worry, this is only in my own little test server.

Anyway, there's the concept of a Collection. All Collections must have a parent (determined through `VCOLLECTIONDEPENDENCYCHAIN`), with the exception of the very top level Collection that is a system collection and cannot be modified.

Each collection can have 0 or more rules, and each rule has a rule type, where the ID of the rule type is saved onto `COLLECTION_RULES` and the matching string for that ID is saved onto `DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES`.

In most cases, a rule is a WQL query, and the rule type is determined by what tables are queried on the WQL query.

However, and this is where the problem lies, collections can also have a query of type 'include' or 'exclude', which basically forces it to borrow the query of another Collection. So effectively you include the results of another Collection's query onto your own Collection, and that's the query.

As far as `COLLECTION_RULES` is concerned, when that happens, the ID of the rule type is 0, which is a value that doesn't exist in `DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES`.

What I was trying to modify was so that when the rule type is 0, get and use the rule type(s) of the highest up parent (not the direct parent since the parent Collection could also have a single include rule, in which case the rule type would still be 0).

The problem is that because each rule can have multiple rule types, it returns multiple rows in some instances.

I tried to invert the query to remove the `SELECT` and use joins only, but failed because I found I always needed to join it to `DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES` and I have nothing to join it on when the rule type = 0.

**EDIT2**

Sample data:

`Collections_G`

[image: Collections_G]

`Collections_L`

[image: Collections_L]

`Collection_Rules`

[image: Collection_Rules]

`DiscoveryArchitectures`

[image: DiscoveryArchitectures]

`vCollectionDependencyChain`

[image: vCollectionDependencyChain]

**Original Query and Original Results**

```
SELECT cg.SiteID,    
         CASE 
             WHEN da.DiscArchKey=5 
             THEN N'vSMS_R_System' 
             ELSE da.BaseTableName END AS TableName 
    FROM Collections_G cg   
    JOIN Collections_L cl ON cg.CollectionID=cl.CollectionID 
    JOIN Collection_Rules cr ON cg.CollectionID=cr.CollectionID   
    JOIN DiscoveryArchitectures da ON cr.ArchitectureKey=da.DiscArchKey   
    WHERE (cg.Flags&4)=4 AND cl.CurrentStatus!=5
```

[image: Original Results]

As you can see from the results picture above, some collections appear multiple times but with different TableNames. This is because each collection have have several rules, and each rule has one `cr.ArchitectureKey`

Also, and more importantly, collections `PS10000B` and `PS10000C` do not show up because their `cr.ArchitectureKey = 0` which is a value that doesn't exist in `da.DiscArchKey`.

My goal is to have collections that have a `cr.ArchitectureKey` appear, but I need to assign them a `cr.ArchitectureKey`

My thought (which is slightly flawed, but don't know enough SQL to make it better, so if someone could help with that it would be appreciated too) was to get use the `da.DiscArchKey` from the top level parent. But the top level parent can have multiple `DiscArchKeys`, which is what is causing the problem.

As mentioned above getting the top level parent is slightly flawed, and ideally I would get the top level `cr.ReferencedCollectionID`. In other words, if `PS10000B` has a `cr.ReferencedCollectionID` of `PS10000C` and `PS10000C` has a `cr.ReferencedCollectionID` of `SMS00002` but because `SMS00002` has no `cr.ReferencedCollectionID` then `SMS00002` is the top level `cr.ReferencedCollectionID` and both `PS10000B` and `PS10000C` should have `da.DiscArchKey`(s) equal to those of `SMS00002`.

Comment: Add a `limit 1` (or `top 1`) if appropriate.  Or use `min()` or `max()`.

Comment: Can't, need all returned rows.

Comment: Then use `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: use `in` where exactly? please elaborate.

Comment: replace `COLLECTIONS_G.SITEID = (SELECT...` with `COLLECTIONS_G.SITEID IN(SELECT...`.

Comment: Same error. The error comes from the select above it, from `SELECT BASETABLENAME FROM DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES`, the select you suggested I modify is already set to `SELECT TOP 1` ..

Comment: What RDBMS, please?  The subquery (and sub-subquery) are essentially a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, and solutions are db-vendor specific.  I'm also a little suspicious of that sub-subquery in the first place...  don't suppose we can get starting sample data and desired results?

Comment: RDBMS = MS SQL. Bit hard to explain here all the sample data and desired results, as you'll make me a lot of questions along the way. Want to set up a chat room?

Comment: Can you please set up a SQL Fiddle with an example of the issue?

Comment: No, the question is the appropriate to place things like sample data and schemas, along with required explanations (if any).  We don't need the full width of the tables, just the columns listed in your query.  And in this case, _potentially_ the script for what appears to be a view.  If it's only in chat, then answers look mysterious.  Especially as that subquery is a pain...

Comment: Added more info. Let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: ... _still_ wanting starting sample data and desired results.  You probably also need a recursive CTE for the "top level" rule type.  I have a bad feeling about the feeling about the design of your tables - it sounds like `discoveryArchitectureKey` may be used as a key for multiple things, which you're not supposed to do...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Added starting sample and desired results. Let me know if you require anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at a wired solution that comes into mind. You may face some syntax errors(most probably in 2nd and 3rd CTE) but it just an idea.

Get each case values in separate CTEs and then combine them at the end.

```
;WITH CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT CG.SITEID,
               CR.COLLECTIONID,
               CG.COLLECTIONNAME
          FROM COLLECTIONS_G CG
          JOIN COLLECTIONS_L CL ON CG.COLLECTIONID=CL.COLLECTIONID
          JOIN COLLECTION_RULES CR ON CG.COLLECTIONID=CR.COLLECTIONID
          WHERE (CG.FLAGS&4)=4 AND CL.CURRENTSTATUS!=5
    ),
    ARCHITECTUREKEY5
    AS
    (
       SELECT C.SITEID,
       C.COLLECTIONID,
       C.COLLECTIONNAME,
        N'vSMS_R_System' as TABLENAME
        FROM CTE C WHERE C.ARCHITECTUREKEY = 5
    ),
    ARCHITECTUREKEY0
    AS
    (
        SELECT C.SITEID,
       C.COLLECTIONID,
       C.COLLECTIONNAME,
       BASETABLENAME as TABLENAME
        FROM CTE C,
         DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES
                JOIN
                COLLECTION_RULES
                ON DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES.DISCARCHKEY =
                        COLLECTION_RULES.ARCHITECTUREKEY
                JOIN
                COLLECTIONS_G
                ON COLLECTION_RULES.COLLECTIONID =
                        COLLECTIONS_G.COLLECTIONID
        WHERE COLLECTIONS_G.SITEID = (SELECT TOP 1 SOURCECOLLECTIONID FROM VCOLLECTIONDEPENDENCYCHAIN WHERE DEPENDENTCOLLECTIONID = C.SITEID ORDER BY LEVEL DESC))
         and C.ARCHITECTUREKEY = 0
    ),
    ARCHITECTUREKEYOTHER
    AS
    (
        SELECT C.SITEID,
       C.COLLECTIONID,
       C.COLLECTIONNAME,
       DA.BASETABLENAME as TABLENAME
       FROM DISCOVERYARCHITECTURES DA, CTE C WHERE DA.DISCARCHKEY=CR.ARCHITECTUREKEY AND C.ARCHITECTUREKEY not in (0,1)
    )
    Select * from ARCHITECTUREKEY5
    UNION
    Select * from ARCHITECTUREKEY0
    UNION
    Select * from ARCHITECTUREKEYOTHER
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that I need the multiple rows it returns. I know what the error says, but I can't limit it to top 1 or something that just returns a single row. I need all rows returned.

Comment: Then you would probably need to concatenate all rows in a single value to make it a single column. So you have to convert these two inner multi-return sub queries into a single value. I would suggest to search for **Stuff with for XML** solution, [example](http://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/)

Comment: That won't work either. I'd have to modify the caller to interpret several rows into a single value, and I don't control and cannot modify the caller.

Comment: ... why are you mixing implicit and explicit `JOIN` syntax?  Don't use implicit (comma-separated `FROM`), always explicitly state joins and conditions.  While I have a feeling multiple `UNION`s may work overall, the problem is the `0`-keyed rows - I'm fairly certain the OP actually needs a recursive call to get a tree structure (although it's difficult to tell without any starting data)